# Redirect to certain web page based on user role not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to redirect a user that is in a specific role to a certain web page.  This doesn't seem to be working.  I have found various suggestions on google but still not working.

Here is my login code:

```
protected void btnLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text, true);
            Session["UserName"] = this.UserName.Text.Trim();
            Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");                
        }

        if (!User.IsInRole("Clients"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Client.aspx"); 
        }

        InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
    }
```

and in my `web.conf`:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" createPersistentCookie="false" cookieProtection="All">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>

</roleManager>
```

Basically I just need to redirect a user in role "Clients" to the Clients.aspx page when they log in.

Please let me know if you require more info. 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

When I do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = this.UserName.Text.Trim();
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserName.Text, "Clients"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Clients.aspx");
        }

    }
```

It then works great.  But am just wondering if this is a good way of doing it?

Comment: Have you debugged this with a breakpoint? It's been a while but IIRC `Response.Redirect` will exit your method and the `if (!User.IsInRole("Clients"))` code will never be hit.

Answer (score 0):

the condition is wrong, you need to remove the `!`

```
if (User.IsInRole("Clients"))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Client.aspx"); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, still not working, but I have updated my question, which I think is a possible solution?